# Smart Wizard in angularJS should validate the form and then go to next step of wizard

Tags: angularjs, wizard

In angularJS, there are many wizard but want the wizard which should work with the specific validations after successful validation it should move to next step. When I am using any wizard its validating any one validation only, if the validation success then next step not able to shown, if click on next its not validating conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need multi step form wizard. check this. might be helpful 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router